# Linux is working very slow in Asus k556uQ

Tags: linux-mint, linux-kernel, cpu

I have ASUS K556UQ series with 7th Generation of Intel CPU kaby Lak 7500 U series. 
I installed windows 10 and every thing is working good. but when I Install any distribution of Linux such mint 18 or Ubuntu 16.04 alongside of windows is 10 it working very very slow. and really I can not working  with this situation.
During installation I don't got an error or some thing else and when i try to work whit Linux in Live mode is fine. but my problem when come it install in my PC.
nothing is  wrong and  when Linux is boot i don't have any error or some thing else.
Can some body help me?
I appreciate that.

Comment: With a recent version of processors it is wise to install recent versions of Linux distributions. So Ubuntu 17 would be better than Ubuntu 16

Answer (score 2):

Kaby Lake CPU's are to be supported by kernel since kernel 4.10.

Run Update Manager -> menu View -> Linux kernels.

Install the latest 4.10 kernel available.